# get value of a cell, or change the value if it's formula - vba

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I am iterating through cells in my worksheet, and getting the vallue of the cell like so:

```
item = Cells(i, 3).value
```

though, sometimes, I have some formulas in the cells, like:

```
=BD=F5=E3
=some string
```

it is type mistakes, but excel generates it as formulas, so when I do on those cells this: `Cells().Value` I get type mismatch error.

is there a way to pass this error? or something like declaring all cells in the worksheet as strings no matter what?

thanks

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code (the relevant parts, if it's long)?  In your Excel file, some cells are set equal to other? Or in your VB macro, you set the values equal?  And "it is type mistakes", can you clarify what you mean by that? Is it errors? (i.e. `#VALUE`, `#N/A`, etc.)

Comment: If we are sure that there are no formulas, only text, then instead of `.Value` try using `.Formula`

Answer (score 2):

- `Cells(r, c).Value` gives the displayed value of the cell
- `Cells(r, c).Text` gives the displayed value returned as a string
- `Cells(r, c).Formula` returns the formula of the cell
- `Cells(r, c).FormulaR1C1` returns the formula in R1C1 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand without the rest of your code, however, if you declare your item in **Cells(i, 3).value** as variant, you can check the type of the data and act accordingly.
For example to ignore errors use IsError(Cells(i, 3).value) etc.